# Incorrect decimal separator used for Pound Sterling currency

Tags: salary, job-change, united-kingdom, contracts, law

The company I work for laid off a few out-of-hours customer service employees and gave me their work between the hours of 6am and 8am, and 6pm to 10pm, my work hours rotate weekly from 6am to 2pm one week, and 2pm to 10pm the next week. I raised a grievance through my manager because I was never consulted about this additional work, I also don't work in the customer service department of my company.

The grievance won and I was set to be given additional money as payment for this cover work, the amount was agreed at £83.33 a month however my contract states £83,33 and is signed by myself and my company at £83,33. I know different countries use different decimal separators and as such £83,33 doesn't exist, it should either be £8,333 or £83.33. Is there a possibility I am entitled to £8,333? or would it just be seen as an error with the comma being where a decimal point should be?

Comment: What would make sense given the context? It's a magnitude of difference, so one of those is obviously right.

Comment: Surely it's pretty obvious that it's a mistype, entering a comma instead of a period..,

Comment: English common law has the slogan "equity abhors a forfeiture." It means that the legal concept of equity -- fairness -- overrules attempts to construe obvious mistakes as binding, especially when they would be very costly to somebody.

Comment: @O.Jones, That sounds like a pretty good answer. You should probably just cut and paste your comment into an answer.

Comment: In many parts of Europe, a comma **is** a decimal point, and a dot is used as a separator.

Comment: Its position in the number seems to make it clear that it was intended as a decimal point. Remember that the other party would argue that it was used as a decimal point if this went to court. If this went to court, given the position in the number, the testimony from your employer, and comparison to your normal salary, don't you think the court would find it to be 83.33 not 8,333?

Comment: Your own statement *"the amount was agreed at £83.33 a month"* settles this

Comment: Someone with such a lack of common sense that they believe they would be entitled to eight thousand pound a month because of a spelling error is really not someone that I would want to employ.

Answer (score 9):

"£83,33" is how one might print the Sterling amount eighty three pounds thirty three pennies in a [locale](http://Locale%20(computer%20software)) in which "," is the decimal separator, so it can certainly exist. This is just like writing €10.33 in the USA or UK, even though many, if not all, countries that use the Euro as their currency use a comma as the decimal separator.

The other use of comma in number formatting is for grouping: $1,000.75, but that is usually by groups of 3 digits in the European countries so it is unlikely to be the intended meaning of the comma in "£83,33".

As pointed out in a comment by [O. Jones](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/15811/o-jones),

> English common law has the slogan "equity abhors a forfeiture."

Even if the comma were ambiguous, which I don't think it is, the next step should be to look at the context, including your normal pay rate, to see which amount is likely to have been intended.

Comment: +1  There are many locales that use a comma as a decimal separator  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a possibility I am entitled to £8,333?

No.

> or would it just be seen as an error with the comma being where a decimal point should be?

Of course it would be seen as a mistake.

On UK keyboards the comma and full stop keys tend to be next to each other.

The amount you want it to be is *100 times* more than what it is.

*You* yourself say the amount agreed was £83.33. Presumably you mean verbally or in written form other than the contract, with at least one other party to that agreement. I.e. one or more people to say the amount agreed was in fact £83.33, the comma is a mistake. And you wouldn't lie to the court, would you?